# MySQL intersect on table if rows found and ignore otherwise

Tags: mysql, sql, logic

I've been working on a database with tables listed as below:

```
Customer
id    INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY
name  VARCHAR

Entrance
id    INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY
desc  VARCHAR

CustomerEntranceRestriction
idEntrance PK, FK to Entrance.id
idCustomer PK, FK to Customer.id
```

The `CustomerEntranceRestriction` table only contains entries where a customer is restricted to the Entrance they can use.  A customer with no records in this table is available to access any entrance.

I want to try and return all the entrances that every customer can access.  My query is as below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   c.id As customer_id, 
   e.id AS entrance_id 
FROM customer c 
JOIN entrance e 
LEFT JOIN CustomerEntranceRestriction cer1 
  ON cer1.idCustomer = cu.id 
LEFT JOIN CustomerEntranceRestriction cer2
  ON cer2.idEntrance = e.id 
WHERE   
   IF(cer1.idCustomer IS NULL, 0, cer2.idEntrance - e.id) = 0 
AND   
   IF(cer2.idEntrance IS NOT NULL,IF(cer2.idCustomer =cu.idCustomer,0,1),0) = 0
```

I think this is working right, but I only have a loose grasp of the logic.  By left joining onto the `CustomerEntranceRestriction` table twice on the partial primary keys, we can can include rows that have `NULL` values for both matches.  Where a match occurs on either `cer1` or `cer2` we check if there is a match to `c.id` or `e.id`, removing those rows where this fails.

Is this sound logic?  I'm not sure if this has a name in relational database circles.

An alternative approach is to take the cross join of all `Customer` and `Entrance` records that have no Customers in the `CustomerEntranceRestrction` and `UNION` those records found in the `CustomerEntranceRestriction` table.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? that really help

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
SELECT c.id As customer_id, 
       e.id AS entrance_id 
FROM customer c CROSS JOIN
     entrance e LEFT JOIN
     CustomerEntranceRestriction cer
     ON cer.idCustomer = c.id AND cer.idEntrance = e.id 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CustomerEntranceRestriction cer2 WHERE cer2.idCustomer = c.idCustomer) OR
      cer.idEntrance IS NOT NULL;
```

This starts with all combinations of customers and entrances.  It then brings in any restrictions.

The `WHERE` clause is saying either (1) the customer has no restrictions or (2) this particular entrance is allowed for the customer.

Comment: I can follow the logic of this and it's much clearer than my attempt.  Can you recommend any resources or books that help with writing queries like this?  I'm trying to teach myself MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to yuor code you could avoid the if condition just using proper where and AND

```
  SELECT DISTINCT 
     c.id As customer_id, 
     e.id AS entrance_id 
  FROM customer c 
  JOIN entrance e 
  LEFT JOIN CustomerEntranceRestriction cer1 
    ON cer1.idCustomer = cu.id 
  LEFT JOIN CustomerEntranceRestriction cer2
    ON cer2.idEntrance = e.id 
  WHERE   cer1.idCustomer IS NULL
  AND   cer2idEntrance IS NOT NULL AND cer2.idCustomer = cu.idCustomer
```